# increase the volume of some portion of audio file

Tags: android, audio

I have an audio WAV file in which there are two speakers. One is a hearing person who has a loud and clear voice, the other one is a deaf person who has a very low voice (In the same audio file). When I listen to the audio file I can hardly hear the voice of the deaf person.

I am building a Speech Recognition system and it fails to detect the sound of the deaf person while it clearly recognizes the voice of the hearing person because the microphone is closer to the hearing person and far away from the deaf person.

How can I increase the volume of the specific portions of the audio file when the deaf person is speaking? Is there any tool for this? or are there any command line solutions?

Comment: After skipping WAVE header, you need to read the remaining values of the bytes in your WAV file. If it's 16-bit then you read `Short`, else if 32-bit just read as `Int` (PS: normally you'd use `Float`, but for your question it might be enough to just get regular numbers)... Each value is the **amplitude** (volume) of that sample, so in a while loop find the typical numbers for loud person, and add an IF statement about `IF lower than loud person THEN increase low-amplitude value`. _EG:_ Max vol = 1.0... If loud = 0.7 and deaf = 0.3 just add +0.4 to the low samples, pushing them up to match...

Comment: Get a free audio tool like Audacity (if Windows OS) to visually see loud/low parts in WAV file, check times for volume (first loud length, first low length). Write code that finds same high/low parts. Export and check your edited file in same audio tool.